# How to get JSON formatting when adding Swashbuckle remarks?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have been following this tutorial on [Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) but when I add remarks they appear as regular text not the JSON shown in the remarks section. Is it possible to get JSON formatting?

Comment: sample code please

Comment: looks fine for me:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/MonthTest/MonthTest_Post
code behind that is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/commit/a0b847f04decc6dd9c45065d15dedc881e801f4d

Comment: only thing I can imagine is your markup syntax is not correct on your remarks

Comment: i had the line immediately following <remarks> indented :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/// <remarks>
/// Sample request:
///
///     POST /Todo
///     {
///        "id": 1,
///        "name": "Item1",
///        "isComplete": true
///     }
///
/// </remarks>
```

Make sure Sample Request is not indented!

Comment: It's very picky.  Document text must NOT be indented, there MUST be a blank line between document text and JSON, and the JSON MUST be indented at least 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

A minor follow up to the accepted answer.
You can create separate areas in the `<remarks>` section:

```
/// <remarks>
/// Sample request:
///
///     POST /Todo
///
/// Result format:
///
///     {
///        "id": 1,
///        "name": "Item1",
///        "isComplete": true
///     }
///
/// </remarks>
```

[image]